# Facebook API Session Conundrum

Tags: php, facebook

I have got a page that allows a user to login, using the Facebook API. But of course the problem is when the user changes pages, the login needs to be re-authorized.

So in my main page I have

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    'cookie' => false,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $_SESSION['fb_session'] = $me;
        $_SESSION['fb_session']['loginUrl'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        $_SESSION['fb_session']['logoutUrl'] = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        $_SESSION['fb_session'] = array_merge($_SESSION['fb_session'], $session);
    } 

    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        unset($_SESSION['fb_session']);
    }
}

if ($_SESSION['fb_session']) {
    $x = $facebook->api("/{$_SESSION['fb_session']['id']}");
    print "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/{$x['id']}/picture' />";                        
    print "<a href='facebook_logout.php'></a>";
} 
else {

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    print "<a href='{$facebook->getLoginUrl()}'>Login to Post Comment</a>";
}
```

And my `facebook_logout.php` looks like:

```
header("location:" . $_SESSION['fb_session']['logoutUrl']);
unset($_SESSION['fb_session']);
```

Now the thing is I have set the session on the first go when I authenticated the user. But what happens if he changes his profile. Or disallows my website in his API.

I have tested this with my profile. It works fine when I allow it. However when I remove the app from my privacy settings I still see my picture and name etc.

Below is the output to `fb_session`

```
[id] => id
[name] => Shahmir Javaid
[first_name] => Shahmir
[last_name] => Javaid
[link] => http://www.facebook.com/shahmirj
[about] => I was Born a n00b, I am still a n00b and il never be not a n00b.
[gender] => male
[locale] => en_GB
[verified] => 1
[updated_time] => 2010-11-22T15:45:22+0000
[loginUrl] => https://
[logoutUrl] => https://
[session_key] => xxx
[uid] => xxx
[expires] => 1290448800
[secret] => xxx
[access_token] => xxx
[sig] => xxx
```

How do I re-authenticate the uid so my expiry time goes back up, of course without getting the user to log back in again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user changes his profile picture(which appears to be all you are using from the profile) because you are pointing to graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture then the updated image will show.  You can use the facebook deauthorize callback url which is in the advanced tab of your application settings to alert your application when a user removes your application.

If you store a list of deauthorized ids and search for that before getting the data then you can unset the session and remove that id from the database, which would display the login url again and remove the facebook connection for that user in your backend.

Comment: All im storing is the uid and the name. The profile picture is retrieved from the `$x = $facebook->api("/{$_SESSION['fb_session']['id']}");` but my point is, dosent that expire. And im sort of lost about the deautorize callback url

Comment: does the Id ever change. Once i have the Id value, will it stop sending me data if i do `$x->api('/Id')` given that the user has not removed me